# make ui-router nested views load progressively

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a dashboard-like page the loads Apple, Pear and Orange data on 3 different ui-views, registered as named views. The overall view resolve is responsible for getting Apple, Pear and Orange data so that it is render by the respective controller/views.

The problem is that Orange data takes 10x more than the rest. So I want to progressively load my named views without waiting for all promises to resolve. Is there any way to achieve/emulate this?

Comment: This capability is planned in the next major release of UI-Router.  Keep an eye on https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/837

Comment: thanks, I will answer my own question then with your link

Answer (score 0):

This feature is planned for the next release. More here https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/837.

Thanks @Chris_T